# Linq To Sql: Capturing the full EXEC statement

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

I am having the hardest time with something that *should* be simple, and I've spent days looking for the right code for it.

I am using Linq-to-SQL against some stored procedures and I wish to be able to log the EXEC statement (params included!).

Parts of the code I have are as follows:

```
Dim ThisDbContext As cRxDataContext = New cRxDataContext(<connection string>)
Dim swLog As IO.StringWriter = New IO.StringWriter
ThisDbContext.Log = swLog
```

Later in the code:

```
Dim ThisResult As ISingleResult(Of Items_GetResult) = ThisDbContext.Items_Get(Param1, Param2, Param3, Param4)
```

And then

```
swLog.toString()
```

*Almosts* give me what I want

> EXEC @RETURN_VALUE = [dbo].[RM_Items_Get] @Param1 = @p0, @Param2 =
>   @p1, @Param3 = @p2
>   -- @p0: Input Int (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [20]
>   -- @p1: Input VarChar (Size = 8000; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [west]
>   -- @p2: Input VarChar (Size = 8000; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) []
>   -- @RETURN_VALUE: Output Int (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Null]
>   -- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 4.7.2046.0

Is there any way to get the EXEC statement filled in with the parameters?  I've come up completely empty on finding out how to capture this when using Linq against PROCs

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is wrong with the output? Does it not already show you the parameters (20, West, , null)?

Comment: I can live with the way it is but I guess I was hoping for a way to get the SQL execution to where I can copy and paste it right into SSMS.